# Is it possible to group a different language settings in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I have a same settings in my settings.json file for a different language files like this

```
"[sass]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
},
"[scss]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
},
"[less]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
},
"[styl]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
},
```

Is it possiple to group that all like this?

```
"[sass, scss, less, styl]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
},
```

Comment: you can set your setting globally for all files

Comment: @rioV8 I don't need it for all files